# ¿Cómo obtener el ID del último registro hecho?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

espero que se encuentren bien! tengo el siguiente problema, estoy mandando datos a través de Fetch API a un archivo PHP para poder guardarlos en MYSQL, logro mandarlos y guardarlos en MYSQL correctamente, el problema es que el id no tengo necesidad de mandarlo por fetch ya que es auto incrementable, entonces quisiera saber como puedo imprimir el id junto con los otros datos que envié a través de fetch api sin necesidad de recargar el sitio web.

Adjunto código JavaScript:

```js
let txtNombre = document.getElementById("txtNombre"); 
let txtApellido = document.getElementById("txtApellido"); 
let txtEmail = document.getElementById("txtEmail"); 
let btnAgregar = document.getElementById("btnAgregar"); 
let pintarTable = document.getElementById("pintar-table"); 

btnAgregar.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
    let form = new FormData(); 
    form.append("nombre", txtNombre.value);
    form.append("apellido", txtApellido.value); 
    form.append("email",txtEmail.value); 

    fetch("insert.php", {
        method: "POST", 
        body: form
    })
        .then(data=>data.json())
        .then(data=>{
            console.log(data); 
        })
});
```

Adjunto codigo PHP:

```
require("conexion.php"); 

$nombre = $_POST["nombre"]; 
$apellido = $_POST["apellido"]; 
$email = $_POST["email"]; 

$sql = "INSERT INTO persona (id,nombre,apellido,email) VALUES (NULL,'$nombre','$apellido','$email')";
$query = $conexion->query($sql); 

if($query){
     echo json_encode($nombre.$apellido.$email);
}
```

Con el json_encode puedo imprimir bien desde javascript el $nombre, el $apellido y el $email, pero no puedo acceder al id que se genera para poder imprimirlo

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado al momento?

Comment: @betaM no mucho hasta el momento, ya que no se me ocurre la forma de poder acceder al id

Comment: @betaM Hasta el momento intenté hacer dos cosas, el primero es hacer en el mismo archivo php después del insert hacer un select, pero el problema es que cuando hago el select me trae todos los registros que tengo y no el ID que necesito. Después se me ocurrió hacer otra función fetch en javascript, haciendo un archivo php aparte con un select y generando un json, este último me resultó, me traía el ID que genera al ingresar datos a mysql, pero para poder mostrar los resultados necesitaba recargar el sitio web, y es así como terminé acá jaja

Comment: Eso esta perfecto (como evidencia), edita tu pregunta y agrega eso ahi

Comment: @betaM ya perfecto, muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considera los siguientes aspectos:

- Si tu id es un valor que no puede quedar `NULL` y que de forma automática se auto genera en cada inserción, entonces esta demás que lo ingreses en la sentencia SQL; es decir puede quedar así:

  ```
  $sql = "INSERT INTO persona (nombre,apellido,email) VALUES ('$nombre','$apellido','$email')";
  ```
- Usa la propiedad `insert_id` para obtener el último id que se auto generó por el `INSERT`
- Accedes a este valor por medio de la variable de conexión, posterior a la acción del `INSERT`
- Para facilitar la lectura y posterior recuperación de los valores deseados, entonces al método `JSON_ENCODE()` le puedes pasar un *array asociativo* con las claves y valores que deseas obtener de vuelta en tu vista.

Código:

```
json_encode([
              'id' => $conexion->insert_id,
              'nombre'   => $nombre, 
              'apellido' => $apellido,
              'email'    => $email,                 
           ]);
```

**Referencia**

- [mysqli insert_id](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.insert-id.php)